# Change icon of another running process with Python

Tags: python, pywinauto

I would like to change in Python the icon of another running process (NOT the icon of an exe made from python with the likes of cx_freeze) in Windows. Is this possible?

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to modify another running process in that way with Python.

Comment: Or at all, in a modern OS.